# CPU Sockets vs. Cores

Tags: vmware-esxi, oracle, central-processing-unit

We are looking at software that is licensed by socket. Right  now our hypervisor (EXSi) underutilizes the 2 socket 8 core processing power it has. Most guests only have 4 virtual cores. In order be compliant with the software I can either a) buy 2 cpus licenses b) buy a dedicated server or c) pull one of the sockets from the hypervisor. C is a non-cash move. My question is, which performs better a vm using 8 virtual cores from 1 socket or 2 sockets?

I should mention that the application is Oracle 11 DB Standard Edition.

Comment: Unfortunately, pulling the socket might not be a feasible approach.  These days, most servers assign RAM DIMMs on a per socket-basis, so you may end up not being able to use all your RAM, or having to buy higher capacity DIMMs.  Also, Oracle licensing is painful.  And evil.  And generally a fate worse than death.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Almost all licensing is painful and evil to deal with. It seems to get worse as the companies get bigger..

Answer (score 2):

Since your multiple core server is bsed on [NUMA architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Uniform_Memory_Access), you'll generally get better performance when the VM is using 8 cores from 1 CPU, instead of 4 cores from each of both CPUs. [VMware will do the right thing most of the time](http://blogs.vmware.com/vsphere/2012/02/vspherenuma-loadbalancing.html).

To understand this issue in more depth, you'll definitely want to read [VMware's NUMA documentation](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.resmgmt.doc/GUID-7E0C6311-5B27-408E-8F51-E4F1FC997283.html).

Whether you need to physically remove a CPU to make Oracle happy is a licensing issue, rather than a technical issue, and is [not something we can help you with](https://serverfault.com/q/215405/126632).

Comment: Agreed that licensing is not something we can help you with. I will say, some companies do make some concessions with processor licensing in a VMWare environment (IBM sub-capacity licensing comes to mind), however, per Oracle (http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/pricing/partitioning-070609.pdf), VMware is considered "soft partitioning" and will require you to license all physical sockets on the host(s).